# Ubuntu 16 Gnome Not detecting Ethernet cable connection

Tags: networking, gnome, ethernet, thinkpad

I' m using a thinkpad t460s with intel network card, the wifi, bluetooth and everything is working fine except the Ethernet port.

I'm connecting but no activity, the menu is not showing wired connection.

In the manual configurations there's no way to create a wired network.

[image: Network configuration settings image.]

Answer (score 0):

I have dicovered the source of the problem after trying a couple of alternatives and all failed. The port was disabled/locked from the BIOS, I was trying to load modules, drivers, firmwares and stuffs but with not success. Hopefully someone will find this answer useful.

TLDR : Enable the **ethernet** port in **BIOS** settings solved the problem.